# Python for-loop to print a triangle

Tags: python, for-loop

**This code was given to me by my professor, and prints a triangle of *s:**

```
def printTriangle(size):
   for i in range(0,size):
      for j in range(0,i+1):
         print "*",
      print
```

**This is my failed attempt to code an inverse of the triangle:**

```
def printInvertedTriangle(size):
   for i in range(size,0):
       for j in range(size,i-1):
           print "*",
       print
```

I have tried this many different ways, but this is how I think it should be, and it only gives me blank space before the program ends.

**My understanding is that this is how his works:**

```
for i in range(start,finish):
    for j in range(start,step):
        print "*",
    print
```

Can anyone explain to me why the first block my professor gave me works, and why mine prints blank space? I *thought* I understood his loop; so what was I doing wrong in mine? What should it look like? I want something based off of his for loop. His goes against what I've been reading in Python tutorials in that he has only (start,step), whereas the tutorials say it goes (start,stop,step).

I got started in programming with JS, and thought that some simple Python loops would be a walk in the park...

Thanks a lot for any and all help!! #noob

Comment: Read carefully: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range *If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1.* In the case where you pass in two positional arguments to range, they will always be start and stop, never step.

Comment: If you want your iteration to start at a high number and count down, you need to specify a negative step. E.g. `range(size-1, -1, -1)` will have `size-1` as its first item and `0` as its last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def printInvertedTriangle(size):
    **for i in range(size,0):**
           for j in range(size,i-1):
               print "*",
           print
```

Your error of having white space shown I believe is as a result of line two. Since this index is counting how many times to step through lines, this needs to still run through x amount of iterations by ranging from (0,size).

In the second for loop, as the lines increase from 1 to 2 to 3 ...etc use variable i and the max (size) to build the reverse triangle.

Try this:

```
def printReverseTriangle(size):
    for i in range(0,size):
        for j in range(i,size):
            print "*",
        print
```

Comment: That is exactly what i needed! Thanks for answering my specific questions, and hashing out my code!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your script outputs nothing is your range doesn't work.

As we can see in the interpreter:

```
>>> range(10,0)
[]
```

It outputs an empty list.

One way to accomplish what you want is to use the reversed() builtin to reverse the list.

```
   for i in reversed(range(0,size)):
      for j in range(0,i+1):
```

To help you in the future, try to use the interpreter more to check the output of things.

You can open any python module in interactive mode, which runs the program and then lets you use the interpreter afterward.

```
python -i script.py
```

Comment: That was a neat trick that worked. I'm using an interactive editor, but I guess I need to check my loop syntax!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program that I had to make for my weekend assignment. It gives a pretty decent reverse triangle as well.

```
def reverse_triangle(n):
    r=n/2+1
    for i in range(r-1,0,-1):
            print" "*(r-i)," *"*i
def main():
    n=input('Enter the size=')
    reverse_triangle(n)
main()
```

Note: In this bit `" *"*i` I put the space before the asterisk because my PC's version of Python 2.7 does not print the pattern symmetrically if the space is not added. You can try it with the space or without it and check if it works for you.